# History feature in a shell

Tags: c, linux, shell, unix, history

I have to implement the hist command includng !k and !!

The 2 functions:

```
void addInHistory(char **history,char *command,int *list_size,int history_capacity)
{
int index=*(list_size);
  if(command[0]!='\n') 
  {
     if(index==history_capacity-1)
     {
        printf("History is full.Deleting commands.");
     }
     else 
     {
         char current_command[COMMAND_SIZE];
         strcpy(current_command,command);
         history[index++]=current_command;       
     }
  }
}
 void printHistory(char **history,int size) 
{
int i;
  for(int i=0;i<=size;i++)
  {
    printf("%d. %s\n",i+1,history[i]);
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is this tagged as C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a C solution

```
 char current_command[COMMAND_SIZE];
 strcpy(current_command,command);
 history[index++]=current_command;
```

should be

```
history[index++]= strdup(command);
```

Be sure to free it when you are done with it.

Comment: No, previously you were saving the string on the stack which goes away as soon as the block is done. The strdup() puts the string on heap where it lives forever until you free it. Your version was not correct, this version should fix that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a good example of linked lists http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/08/c-linked-list-example/

you would just replace int val with your char*.
but your method will work if you fix one line of code

your bug is right here

```
     char current_command[COMMAND_SIZE];
```

current_command goes out of scope after the else statement is over and thus gets deleted. instead do this

```
     char * current_command = new char[COMMAND_SIZE];
```

then your code should work

Comment: Oops I just saw that you posted (C code) the way i did it is the c++ way. if you are using strictly c you would have to do maloc instead of new, but I dont know the exact syntax for it, Sorry

Comment: The linked list would have the advantage of not running out of space(short of running out of memory on your computer) but it is much more simple to make it work I added a link to a linked list example that is pretty good

Comment: @CharlieBurns method is better than calling maloc

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use (like `bash` does) the [GNU readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library. You'll then use the [readline](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC24) function to read interactively a line from the terminal and [add_history](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/history.html#SEC11) to add a line to the history list (and you could also [customize the autocompletion](https://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/readline.html#SEC45))